# How to addclass to parent or target class with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How to add toggle class to .parent after click on

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="/" @click="??????">
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a conditional class attribute

```
<template>
  <div class="parent" :class="{ toggle: clicked }">
    <a href="/" @click="clicked = !clicked">Toggle me</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
return default {
   data () {
     return {
        clicked: false
     }
   }
}
</script>
```